# Hash function for anonymizing list of usernames

Tags: java, facebook, hash

I have an `.xls` file recording a list of public Facebook posts on a specific page, including timestamps and authors of the messages.
For research reasons I'd like to share it online, but, as I want to preserve the privacy of commenters, I'd like to turn their names into alphanumeric strings.

So I'm thinking about a possible hashing function in Java for the authors' names. What would you suggest? I'd like it to be as injective as possible (two different strings don't get the same hash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) shall do the job for you. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-md5-hashing-example/) you can find how it can be done in java

Answer (score 2):

Try MessageDigest and Base64

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] d = md.digest("John Smith".getBytes());
String str = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(d);
System.out.println(str);
```

output

```
5ho1h7P3oUK4x7kmPIL4EZOY7Lc=
```

Answer (score 1):

A good bet would be SHA-1 or RIPEMD-160. They're cryptographically strong, even MD5 would be enough in your case.